# PCF DB2 User Provided Service

Tags: spring-boot, db2, pcf

I created a User Provided Service for db2 in PCF using below command

```
cf cups db2-service -p "jdbcUrl,user,password"
```

and bound the service to application and can see the environment variables in VCAP Services

```
"VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "user-provided": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:db2://xxx.yyy.com:446/zzz",
     "password": "aaaaa",
     "user": "bbbbb"
    },
    "label": "user-provided",
    "name": "db2-service",
    "syslog_drain_url": "",
    "tags": [],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

When pushing the app I am getting the error "Null userid cannot be supported", I tried changing the user param to userid/username but it still gives me the same error, Could you please point out if the service params are correctly provided.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][t4][10205][11234][4.13.80] Null userid is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][t4][10205][11234][4.13.80] Null userid is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:677) ~[db2jcc4.jar!/:na]
```

Comment: I am able to deploy the app by setting the User Provided Service having only the jdbcUrl parameter in below format. jdbc:db2://my.db.server.com:446/DBName:user=USERID;password=PASSWORD; But now intermittently getting below exception org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection But it works fine other times

Comment: Instead of User Provided Service if I give the connectivity details in properties file it all works fine without any issues.